# How to modify the code to print out the array v2

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

My code uses a for Loop to copy and paste the contents of V1 -> V2. I would like to see the output of v2 using cout but i am unsure where to put that line of code.

```
void copy_fct();

int main()
{

copy_fct();


}


void copy_fct()
{
    int v1[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int v2[10];

    for (int i=0; i!=10; ++i){
        v2[i]=v1[i];

    }

}
```

Comment: Just print each element as you copy it?

Comment: This is my first day of learning how to code, so i'm not too sure how to do that. When I write cout << v2[5]; right under copy_fct(); in my main function, I get an error saying 'v2' was not declared.

Comment: Put the `cout << v2[i];` below the `v2[i]=v1[i];`.

Comment: @MichaelKaribi `v2` is declared in `copy_fct`, so it's only accessible from there.

Comment: Hey @Blaze, I tried that and it says "error 'cout' was not declared in this scope".

Comment: Then I would argue that you're going to fast and need to slow down a bit. Do you have [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read? Then follow it, learning bit by bit. And if you don't have a good book, then I suggest you invest in one. It will help you in the long run.

Comment: Put `std::cout` instead of `cout`. Make sure `<iosteam>` is included.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is an exercise from the very first chapter of 'The c++ Programming Language - Fourth Edition - Bjarne Stroustrup' .

However, in their example, they didn't print out the array and I wanted to print it out to see if it's working.

Comment: I would just like to thank everyone for your help! The answers below seem to have worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
void copy_fct();

int main()
{

copy_fct();


}


void copy_fct()
{
    int v1[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int v2[10];

    for (int i=0; i!=10; ++i){
        v2[i]=v1[i];
        std::cout << v2[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program design the name of the function `copy_fct` does not make great sense because it copies nothing passed to the function by the user. It deals with its local variables.

It seems you mean something like the following.

```
#include <iostream>

void copy_fct( const int a1[], size_t n, int a2[] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a2[i] = a1[i];
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int v1[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int v2[N];

    copy_fct( v1, N, v2 );

    for ( int item : v2 ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The same task can be done using standard algorithms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int v1[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int v2[N];

    std::copy( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ), std::begin( v2 ) );

    std::copy( std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );

    return 0;
}
```